# A Java Singleton example, and can I change code like this?

Tags: java, singleton

Here's the original code that create a singleton class:

```
package com.hsp.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


final public class MySessionFactory {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    private MySessionFactory() {

    }

    static {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and my question is, can I declare sessionFactory directly using :

```
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
 new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

so that the whole code can be as follows :

```
package com.hsp.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


final public class MySessionFactory {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
    new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    private MySessionFactory() {

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

if not, then what is the difference between the two code blocks? and is there any defects in the second one?

Comment: I would add a `final` to the second example, and in the first do a `private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;` (instead of the `null` you had before). Then they are identical at the byte code level, initialization statements have strong guarantees.

Comment: As general rule, it's encourage to use a `enum` instance - [Why Enum Singleton are better in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html) and [Java Singletons Using Enum](https://dzone.com/articles/java-singletons-using-enum) may shed some more light on the subject

Comment: "and my question is, can I declare sessionFactory directly using..." - the answer is "yes"!

Comment: To my knowledge really there is no much difference. Its more of convenience. As this is just one of line of code I would personally prefer to use

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory =  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

But if it has more than 1 line of code I would rather initialize in a static block.

Comment: @alfasin   In my opinion if the static block contains only one line of operation to sessionFactory, then we can merge this block into the private static SessionFactory declaration. but if the block contains more than one line of code, then it is more convenient to use static block. is that right?

Comment: @Anil yes, this is my understanding.

Comment: `static { ...}` is used for initialization during class load. If you need to run a few steps for the initialization you simply *cannot* do it in one line. If you can do it in the same line of declaration I honestly don't understand why would anyone want to do it separately in a static block: it doesn't have any added value and it makes the code less readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to separate the static variable declaration and static operation block .